# How do I size and Position an item relative to its container

Tags: html, css

Im Completely new to HTML and i want to Position and Size an Item relative to its Container. I copied this Code (https://codepen.io/Tectonics0x3F/pen/EfAgr) and if I changed the top and left Percentage to 25% and 25% for example,then the Box was 25% below the top of the container and 25% more in the right direction 
same with the size of the Box if I changed Height and Width the Box was as High as 25% of the Container height and as wide as 25% of the Container length. But if I'm doing this in my code the Boxes and the Container are just going anywhere. I think the Problem is that the Boxes are not really in the Container but i don't know how to do this. And idk if you need to know this but what i want to do is a Menu with those boxes in the Container. Thank you in advance for help and sorry for my bad English.

My Codes

```css
   body{
  background-image:url('../images/bg24.jpg');
  color: #fff;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size:16px;
  line-height: 1.6em;
  margin:0;
  background-repeat:repeat; 
  margin: auto;
}


#container {
  height:70%;
  width:90%;
  margin:auto;
  top:25%;
  left:5%;
  border: 5px solid white;
  position:relative;
}



.button {
      background-color: #474B4F;  
      border: 2px solid Black;
      color: white;
      padding: 5% 5%;
      text-align: center;
      text-decoration: none;
      display: inline;
      font-size: 20px;
      cursor: pointer;
      border-radius: 5px; 
      box-sizing: border-box;
}

#button1{
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position:absolute;
}

#button2{
 margin-top:0;
 margin-left: 25%;
 position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<body>
 <div id="container">
  <div id="button1">
  <a href="Somepage.html" class="button">clickme1</a>
  <div id="button2">
  <a href="Somepage2.html" class="button">clickme2</a>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the simplest way you can achieve the menu and if you want a more detailed walkthrough reply to this.

```css
.button {
     background-color: #474B4F;  
     border: 2px solid Black;
     color: white;
     padding: 5% 5%;
     text-align: center;
     text-decoration: none;
     font-size: 20px;
     cursor: pointer;
     border-radius: 5px; 
     box-sizing: border-box;
}
#button1,#button2 {
margin:12px;/* If you want spacing between them */
display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="button1">
        <a href="Somepage.html" class="button">clickme1</a>
        </div>
        <div id="button2">
        <a href="Somepage2.html" class="button">clickme2</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you this is what I was looking for. it would be really nice if you could give me a walkthrough but you don't have to if you dont have enough time or something like this.